# How to upgrade Node.js on Nodester

Tags: node.js, upgrade, nodester

I'm trying to upgrade to Node v0.6.17. I followed the instructions in this post:

http://blog.nodester.com/

but I'm still running version 0.4.9

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several issues why it's not working. It'd be good if you paste your package.json somewhere.

FWIW To upgrade the node.js you just need to add the next key/value pair:

```
"node":"0.6.17"
```

In the top level of the package.json, it's case-sensitive and it can be only one of the versions that the api returns when you request http://nodester.com/env/version.

In other words your package.json should look like this:

```
{
   "name":"jwerre",
   "description":"my awesome app",
   "version":"0.0.1",
   "node":"0.6.17"
   ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, My mistake was using :
`"engines": {
    "node": "0.6.17"
}` instead of `node:0.6.17`